# Estilo de una SQL Query en PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, css

Tengo un output en .PHP de una consulta a una base de datos a partir de un parámetro introducido mediante formulario HTML, como puedo añadirle un estilo a esa salida de información?

Algo del código PHP:

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultAll) > 0) {
while($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAll)){
echo "Precio: ".$rowData["Precio"]."€".'
';

Output:[image: Resultado]

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es tu problema específico? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué resultados obtienes? ¿Qué esperas obtener? ¿Hay algún error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.